# Can I return something specific when the user calls an undefined property/method?

Tags: c#, .net

Writing an object using the fluent pattern, and would like to have any undefined property (or method) return the object (*this*).

Example:

```
public class Please {
  private float nDegrees;
  public Please Rotate(float nDegrees) {
    this.nDegrees = nDegrees;
    return this;
  }

  // code to make all other calls => this;
}

var foo = new Please().Rotate(n).Degrees;            // Degrees should return the Instance of Please it was called on
var bar = new Please().Rotate(n).To.Do.The.Thing;    // should also return the instance of please it was called on
```

Comment: Can you please, clarify, what you mean under 'call an undefined method"

Comment: This is sort of possible with [`DynamicObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.8) but it would add a lot of complexity and give up compile-time safety. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk as shown in the example. Degrees has not been defined in the class `Please`, but would return something. In my case it simply would return the object it was called on.
@JohnWu only syntatic sugar. I suspect it's something I can't do, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: What type are you expecting `nDegrees` to be? You haven't declared it; do you mean for `Rotate` to return `Please` instead of `float`?

Comment: Any call to an undefined property or method would result in a compilation failure. Dynamic or reflection could do the trick, but again, you lose compile time verification. Usually, unlike dynamic languages, when a property doesn't exist, it means that it should never be called.

Comment: maybe he's looking for generics? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: @JoeSewell I've updated the example to include the code for Rotate (also realized Rotate would be returning a Please object, not a float, my bad). I would like to get the Please object back if I call any arbitrary method / property.

Comment: @Alejandro "Maybe but you shouldn't" is acceptable to me. Thank you.